# UV4L raspicam webstreaming in H264

Tags: camera, raspicam, streaming, uv4l, h264

I'm having some trouble getting H264 streaming to work. I've been digging around a little and it seems the problem is that UV4L is sending raw H264, which is not directly playable in Chrome. Does anyone know of any way to do this? Even in VLC with the "demux=h264" flag I get no video, but I see data received with my chosen bitrate. The MJPEG stream works fine. The end goal of this project is to embed a live H264 video stream on a webpage, served over 4G/LTE. Getting help to get this working would be GREATLY appreciated.

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487978/how-to-embed-h264-video-file-in-html-webpage-using-video-tags/29489356

Answer (score 1):

The only way to play H264 video streams with *standard* web technologies is WebRTC. UV4L has been supporting WebRTC for years now, and the [project website](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/) is plenty of examples, tutorials and demos made for the Raspberry Pi showing how to run custom web applications with UV4L itself providing H264 hardware-encoded streams in the pages.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are some issues with timestamps in BCM2835 (for instance, Pi Zero) which affect the standard kernel driver for the RPi camera:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1836

The fix should be available on kernel release 5.8.